# Generate new variable based on start and stop date in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I am in need of assistance. I have some data that looks similar to this.

```
   Machine   Start      Stop           ServiceType 
1       XX 2014-12-04       <NA>          AA
2       XX 2013-09-05 2013-11-05          BB
3       XX 2013-11-21 2014-09-25          BB
4       XX 2013-10-11 2014-11-18          BB
5       XX 2021-12-03       <NA>          AA
6       XX 2020-08-06 2022-09-15          AA
7       XX 2021-06-10       <NA>          BB
8       YY 2020-01-17       <NA>          BB
9       YY 2015-11-04 2018-04-30          BB
10      YY 2016-05-28 2019-03-21          BB
11      YY 2019-09-27       <NA>          BB
12      YY 2018-01-05       <NA>          AA
```

So what I would like to do is generate a new variable, say Maintenance or something, that's either `AA` or `BB` if only one service types is active or `CC` if both `AA` and `BB` are overlapping. Like,

```
   Machine   Date          Maintenance        
1       XX 2013-09-05          BB
2       XX 2013-11-21          BB
3       XX 2013-10-11          AA
4       XX 2014-12-04          CC   
5       XX 2021-12-03          AA
6       YY 2015-11-04          BB
7       YY 2016-05-28          CC
8       YY 2020-01-17          BB
```

I have been working with `dplyr` and `lubridate` but I am a bit unsure how to perform this task, any help would be kind.

ps. `NA`'s in this case can be considered a machine is on that service forever.

Comment: There are twelve unique `Start` values but only eight rows in your output. How are you filtering? Almost the same, how are you determining the output `Date` values?

Comment: The condition for creating a new variable is unclear here, how should Maintenance be set?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. The conditions would be if `ServiceType` is `AA`, then `Maintenance` is set to `AA`. If `ServiceType` is `BB`, then `Maintenance` is set to `BB`. Now, considering there's dates where these two service types may overlap, i.e. `AA & BB`, then `Maintenance` would be set to `CC`. Also, regarding the type of output for `Date` I am unsure how to properly work with dates in R. Having only one time-variable would help with plotting/summarising later on though.

Comment: Row 5 and 7 overlaps but why is it not CC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some inconsistencies in your question (some variables do overlap but they are considered separate in your expected output), here's a way to group by overlapping values and get somewhat your expected output. This solution uses the `ivs`, `tidyverse`, and `lubridate` libraries:

```r
library(ivs)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(Stop = ifelse(Stop == "<NA>", Start, Stop),
         across(c(Start, Stop), ymd),
         Stop = if_else(Stop == Start, Stop + days(1), Stop),
         ivs = iv(Start, Stop)) %>% 
  group_by(Machine, gp = iv_identify_group(ivs)) %>% 
  summarise(ServiceType = toString(unique(ServiceType)),) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(gp = iv_start(gp),
         ServiceType = ifelse(ServiceType %in% c("BB, AA", "AA, BB"), "CC", ServiceType))

# A tibble: 6 × 3
  gp         Machine ServiceType
  <date>     <chr>   <chr>      
1 2013-09-05 XX      BB         
2 2014-12-04 XX      AA         
3 2020-08-06 XX      CC         
4 2015-11-04 YY      CC         
5 2019-09-27 YY      BB         
6 2020-01-17 YY      BB
```

data

```r
df <- read.table(header = T, text = "   Machine   Start      Stop           ServiceType 
1       XX 2014-12-04       NA          AA
2       XX 2013-09-05 2013-11-05          BB
3       XX 2013-11-21 2014-09-25          BB
4       XX 2013-10-11 2014-11-18          BB
5       XX 2021-12-03       <NA>          AA
6       XX 2020-08-06 2022-09-15          AA
7       XX 2021-06-10       <NA>          BB
8       YY 2020-01-17       <NA>          BB
9       YY 2015-11-04 2018-04-30          BB
10      YY 2016-05-28 2019-03-21          BB
11      YY 2019-09-27       <NA>          BB
12      YY 2018-01-05       <NA>          AA
")
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not get the exact output that you posted, but then again my expected output was subpar. I'll tinker some with this and hopefully I'll get it going. Thanks again for the help!